# How does Fedex and UPC code functionality in Google search work? Can my site get similar treatment from Google?

Tags: seo, google

When I search for a `UPC` code in Google, on top of the screen there are two special links to FedEX and UPCDatabase.com. Obviously the way it works is that Google recognizes the strings as valid `UPC` codes and then loads these "smart links". What are these "smart links" called and how have Fedex and UPCDatabase.com implemented them to have them linked to their website?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Special informatonal sections at the top of search results are usually called "Google OneBox".  [Here is a "museum" of some different oneboxes](http://blogoscoped.com/archive/2007-01-17-n67.html):

> - [Aircraft Registration Number](http://blogoscoped.com/files/onebox-museum/aircraft-registration-number.png)
> - [Airport Conditions](http://blogoscoped.com/files/onebox-museum/airport-conditions.png)
> - [Book Results](http://blogoscoped.com/files/onebox-museum/book-results.png)
> - [Calculator](http://blogoscoped.com/files/onebox-museum/calculator.png)
> - [Calculator Currency Conversion](http://blogoscoped.com/files/onebox-museum/calculator-currency-conversion.png)
> - [Current Local Time](http://blogoscoped.com/files/onebox-museum/current-local-time.png)
> - [Definition](http://blogoscoped.com/files/onebox-museum/definition.png) (and [definition page](http://blogoscoped.com/files/onebox-museum/definition-page.png))
> - [FCC Equipment Database](http://blogoscoped.com/files/onebox-museum/fcc-equipment-database.png)
> - [Flights](http://blogoscoped.com/files/onebox-museum/flights.png)
> - [Flight Status](http://blogoscoped.com/files/onebox-museum/flight-status.png)
> - [Google Base](http://blogoscoped.com/files/onebox-museum/google-base.png) (jobs)
> - [Image Results](http://blogoscoped.com/files/onebox-museum/image-results.png)
> - [Image Results and Map](http://blogoscoped.com/files/onebox-museum/image-results-and-map.png)
> - [Local](http://blogoscoped.com/files/onebox-museum/local.png)
> - [Local Results and Flights](http://blogoscoped.com/files/onebox-museum/local-results-and-flights.png)
> - [Map](http://blogoscoped.com/files/onebox-museum/map.png)
> - [Map and Refinement](http://blogoscoped.com/files/onebox-museum/map-and-refinement.png)
> - [Movie Showtimes](http://blogoscoped.com/files/onebox-museum/movie-showtimes.png)
> - [Music Results](http://blogoscoped.com/files/onebox-museum/music-results.png)
> - [News](http://blogoscoped.com/files/onebox-museum/news.png)
> - [Patents](http://blogoscoped.com/files/onebox-museum/patents.png)
> - [Phonebook Results](http://blogoscoped.com/files/onebox-museum/phonebook-results.png)
> - [Product Search Results](http://blogoscoped.com/files/onebox-museum/product-search-results.png)
> - [Q&A](http://blogoscoped.com/files/onebox-museum/q-and-a.png)
> - [Refinement](http://blogoscoped.com/files/onebox-museum/refinement.png) (Google Co-op)
> - [Related](http://blogoscoped.com/files/onebox-museum/related.png)
> - [Scholarly Articles](http://blogoscoped.com/files/onebox-museum/scholarly-articles.png)
> - [Spelling Correction](http://blogoscoped.com/files/onebox-museum/spelling-correction.png)
> - [Stocks](http://blogoscoped.com/files/onebox-museum/stocks.png)
> - [Trailer](http://blogoscoped.com/files/onebox-museum/trailer.png)
> - [UPC Number](http://blogoscoped.com/files/onebox-museum/upc-number.png)
> - [Weather](http://blogoscoped.com/files/onebox-museum/weather.png)

Google engineers implement these when they feel they would be useful for users.   Webmasters don't have a good way to suggest to Google that something similar should be done for the data on their own site.

Comment: This is very unfair, I'm going to contact Google regarding this. I think all companies in every industry should at least be able to apply to be included in the One Box feature!